# What is the purpose of mock objects?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking

I am new to unit testing, and I continously hear the words 'mock objects' thrown around a lot. In layman's terms, can someone explain what mock objects are, and what they are typically used for when writing unit tests?

Comment: They're a tool for massively overengineering things with flexibility you don't need for the problem at hand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is Mocking?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665812/what-is-mocking)

Answer (score 420, accepted):

Since you say you are new to unit testing and asked for mock objects in "layman's terms", I'll try a layman's example.

## Unit Testing

Imagine unit testing for this system:

```
cook <- waiter <- customer
```

It's generally easy to envision testing a low-level component like the `cook`:

```
cook <- test driver
```

The test driver simply orders different dishes and verifies the cook returns the correct dish for each order.

Its harder to test a middle component, like the waiter, that utilizes the behavior of other components.  A naive tester might test the waiter component the same way we tested the cook component:

```
cook <- waiter <- test driver
```

The test driver would order different dishes and ensure the waiter returns the correct dish.  Unfortunately, that means that this test of the waiter component may be dependent on the correct behavior of the cook component.  This dependency is even worse if the cook component has any test-unfriendly characteristics, like non-deterministic behavior (the menu includes chef's surprise as an dish), lots of dependencies (cook won't cook without his entire staff), or lot of resources (some dishes require expensive ingredients or take an hour to cook).

Since this is a waiter test, ideally, we want to test just the waiter, not the cook.  Specifically, we want to make sure the waiter conveys the customer's order to the cook correctly and delivers the cook's food to the customer correctly.

Unit testing means testing units independently, so a better approach would be to isolate the component under test (the waiter) using what [Fowler calls test doubles (dummies, stubs, fakes, mocks)](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#TheDifferenceBetweenMocksAndStubs).

```
    -----------------------
   |                       |
   v                       |
test cook <- waiter <- test driver
```

Here, the test cook is "in cahoots" with the test driver.  Ideally, the system under test is designed so that the test cook can be easily substituted ([injected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)) to work with the waiter without changing production code (e.g. without changing the waiter code).

## Mock Objects

Now, the test cook (test double) could be implemented different ways:

- a fake cook - a someone pretending to be a cook by using frozen dinners and a microwave,
- a stub cook - a hot dog vendor that always gives you hot dogs no matter what you order, or
- a mock cook - an undercover cop following a script pretending to be a cook in a sting operation.

See [Fowler's article for the more specifics about fakes vs stubs vs mocks vs dummies](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#TheDifferenceBetweenMocksAndStubs), but for now, let's focus on a mock cook.

```
    -----------------------
   |                       |
   v                       |
mock cook <- waiter <- test driver
```

A big part of unit testing the waiter component focuses on how the waiter interacts with the cook component . A mock-based approach focuses on fully specifying what the correct interaction is and detecting when it goes awry.

The mock object knows in advance what is supposed to happen during the test (e.g. which of its methods calls will be invoked, etc.) and the mock object knows how it is supposed to react (e.g. what return value to provide).  The mock will indicate whether what really happens differs from what is supposed to happen.  A custom mock object could be created from scratch for each test case to execute the expected behavior for that test case, but a mocking framework strives to allow such a behavior specification to be clearly and easily indicated directly in the test case.

The conversation surrounding a mock-based test might look like this:

> **test driver** to **mock cook**: *expect a hot dog order and give him this dummy hot dog in response*
>
> **test driver** (posing as customer) to **waiter**: *I would like a hot dog please*
>   **waiter** to **mock cook**: *1 hot dog please*
>   **mock cook** to **waiter**: *order up: 1 hot dog ready (gives dummy hot dog to waiter)*
>   **waiter** to **test driver**: *here is your hot dog (gives dummy hot dog to test driver)*
>
> **test driver**: TEST SUCCEEDED!

But since our waiter is new, this is what could happen:

> **test driver** to **mock cook**: *expect a hot dog order and give him this dummy hot dog in response*
>
> **test driver** (posing as customer) to **waiter**: *I would like a hot dog please*
>   **waiter** to **mock cook**: *1 hamburger please*
>   **mock cook** stops the test: *I was told to expect a hot dog order!*
>
> **test driver** notes the problem: TEST FAILED! - the waiter changed the order

or

> **test driver** to **mock cook**: *expect a hot dog order and give him this dummy hot dog in response*
>
> **test driver** (posing as customer) to **waiter**: *I would like a hot dog please*
>   **waiter** to **mock cook**: *1 hot dog please*
>   **mock cook** to **waiter**: *order up: 1 hot dog ready (gives dummy hot dog to waiter)*
>   **waiter** to **test driver**: *here is your french fries (gives french fries from some other order to test driver)*
>
> **test driver** notes the unexpected french fries: TEST FAILED! the waiter gave back wrong dish

It may be hard to clearly see the difference between mock objects and stubs without a contrasting stub-based example to go with this, but this answer is way too long already :-)

Also note that this is a pretty simplistic example and that mocking frameworks allow for some pretty sophisticated specifications of expected behavior from components to support comprehensive tests.  There's plenty of material on mock objects and mocking frameworks for more information.

Comment: This is a great explanation, but aren't you to some extent testing the  implementation of waiter? In your case, it's probably okay because you're checking that it uses the correct API, but what if there are different ways to do it, and waiter might choose one or the other? I thought the point of unit testing was to test the API, and not the implementation. (This is a question I always find myself asking when I read about mocking.)

Comment: Thanks.  I can't say whether we're testing the "implementation" without seeing (or defining) the spec for the waiter.  You may assume that the waiter is allowed to cook the dish himself or fill the order down the street, but I assume the spec for the waiter includes using the intended chef - after all, the production chef is an expensive, gourmet chef and we'd prefer our waiter to use him.  Without that spec, I guess I"d have to conclude you are right - the waiter can fill the order however it wants in order to be "correct".  OTOH, without a spec, the test is meaningless. [continued ...]

Comment: NEVERTHELESS, you make a great point that leads into the fantastic topic of white box vs black box unit testing.  I don't think there's a industry consensus that says unit testing must be black-box instead of white-box ("test the API, not the implementation").  I think that the best unit testing likely needs to be a combination of the two to balance test brittleness against code coverage and test case completeness.

Comment: This answer is according to me not technical enough. I want to know why I should use mock object when I can use real objects.

Comment: I'm glad I finally found this explanation. What a wonderful analogy you used here. This brought so much clarity to me. Previously I had never really understood the value of mocking, but it really really clicked with this explanation. Indeed, in many scenarios it can be questionable to choose to pursue this mode of testing when the additional effort associated with "building a proper box" around the component under test, capturing all its permitted behavior, could be comparable to the effort involved in directly improving or debugging the whole system. So it would be wise to consider that...

Comment: ... And yet, in a well-established system, a deployed system, an (overly) complex system, or one which has all of those properties, when changing things is out of the question, this is a conceptually pure approach to isolating a subsystem in order to establish a sane process with which to iterate on improving its quality. You'll recognize this scenario once you've been in one. You'll want all the help you can get. Ya, I had already read the Fowler article. It was sorely lacking in this layperson common sense context.

Answer (score 30):

A Mock Object is an object that substitutes for a real object.  In object-oriented programming, mock objects are simulated objects that mimic the behavior of real objects in controlled ways.

A computer programmer typically creates a mock object to test the behavior of some other object, in much the same way that a car designer uses a crash test dummy to simulate the dynamic behavior of a human in vehicle impacts.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object

Mock objects allow you to set up test scenarios without bringing to bear large, unwieldy resources such as databases.  Instead of calling a database for testing, you can simulate your database using a mock object in your unit tests.  This frees you from the burden of having to set up and tear down a real database, just to test a single method in your class.

The word "Mock" is sometimes erroneously used interchangeably with "Stub."  The differences between the two words are [described here.](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#TheDifferenceBetweenMocksAndStubs)  Essentially, a mock is a stub object that also includes the expectations (i.e. "assertions") for proper behavior of the object/method under test.

For example:

```
class OrderInteractionTester...
  public void testOrderSendsMailIfUnfilled() {
    Order order = new Order(TALISKER, 51);
    Mock warehouse = mock(Warehouse.class);
    Mock mailer = mock(MailService.class);
    order.setMailer((MailService) mailer.proxy());

    mailer.expects(once()).method("send");
    warehouse.expects(once()).method("hasInventory")
      .withAnyArguments()
      .will(returnValue(false));

    order.fill((Warehouse) warehouse.proxy());
  }
}
```

Notice that the `warehouse` and `mailer` mock objects are programmed with the expected results.

Comment: The definition you've given differs not the least from "stub object," and as such does not explain what a mock object is.

Comment: Another correction "the word 'Mock' is sometimes _erroneously_ used interchangeably with 'stub'".

Comment: @Myst: The usage of the two words is not universal; it varies among authors. Fowler says so, and the Wikipedia article says so. However, feel free to edit in the change and remove your downvote. :)

Comment: I agree with Robert: usage of the word "mock" tends to vary across the industry, but there is *no* set definition according to my experience except that its typically NOT the actually object being tested, rather it exists to facilitate testing where using the actual object or all parts of it would be very inconvenient and of little consequence.

Answer (score 17):

Mock objects are simulated objects that mimic the behavior of the real ones. Typically you write a mock object if:

- The real object is too complex to incorporate it in a unit testing (For
  example a networking communication,
  you can have a mock object that
  simulate been the other peer)
- The result of your object is non
  deterministic
- The real object is not yet available

Answer (score 13):

A Mock object is one kind of a [Test Double](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Double.html). You are using mockobjects to test and verify the protocol/interaction of the class under test with other classes.

Typically you will kind of 'program' or 'record' expectations : method calls you expect your class to do to an underlying object.

Let's say for example we are testing a service method to update a field in a Widget. And that in your architecture there is a WidgetDAO which deals with the database. Talking with the database is slow and setting it up and cleaning afterwards is complicated, so we will mock out the WidgetDao.

let's think what the service must do : it should get a Widget from the database, do something with it and save it again.

So in pseudo-language with a pseudo-mock library we would have something like :

```
Widget sampleWidget = new Widget();
WidgetDao mock = createMock(WidgetDao.class);
WidgetService svc = new WidgetService(mock);

// record expected calls on the dao
expect(mock.getById(id)).andReturn(sampleWidget);   
expect(mock.save(sampleWidget);

// turn the dao in replay mode
replay(mock);

svc.updateWidgetPrice(id,newPrice);

verify(mock);    // verify the expected calls were made
assertEquals(newPrice,sampleWidget.getPrice());
```

In this way we can easily test drive development of classes which depend on other classes.

Answer (score 9):

When unit testing some part of a computer program you ideally want to test just the behavior of that particular part.

For example, look at the pseudo-code below from an imaginary piece of a program that uses another program to call print something:

```
If theUserIsFred then
    Call Printer(HelloFred)
Else
   Call Printer(YouAreNotFred)
End
```

If you were testing this, you would mainly want to test the part that looks at if the user is Fred or not. You don't really want to test the `Printer` part of things. That would be another test.

**This** is where Mock objects come in. They pretend to be other types of things. In this case you would use a Mock `Printer` so that it would act just like a real printer, but wouldn't do inconvenient things like printing.

---

There are several other types of pretend objects that you can use that aren't Mocks. The main thing that makes Mocks Mocks is that they can be configured with behaviors and with expectations.

**Expectations** allow your Mock to raise an error when it is used incorrectly. So in the above example, you could want to be sure that the Printer is called with HelloFred in the "user is Fred" test case. If that doesn't happen your Mock can warn you.

**Behavior in Mocks** means that for example, of your code did something like:

```
If Call Printer(HelloFred) Returned SaidHello Then
    Do Something
End
```

Now you want to test what your code does when the Printer is called and returns SaidHello, so you can set up the Mock to return SaidHello when it is called with HelloFred.

One good resource around this is Martin Fowlers post [Mocks Aren't Stubs](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html)

Answer (score 7):

Mock and stub objects are a crucial part of unit testing. In fact they go a long way to make sure you are testing **units**, rather than **groups** of units.

In a nutshell, you use stubs to break SUT's (System Under Test) dependency on other objects and mocks to do that **and** verify that SUT called certain methods/properties on the dependency. This goes back to fundamental principles of unit testing - that the tests should be easily readable, fast and not requiring configuration, which using all real classes might imply.

Generally, you can have more than one stub in your test, but you should only have one mock. This is because mock's purpose is to verify behavior and your test should only test one thing.

Simple scenario using C# and Moq:

```
public interface IInput {
  object Read();
}
public interface IOutput {
  void Write(object data);
}

class SUT {
  IInput input;
  IOutput output;

  public SUT (IInput input, IOutput output) {
    this.input = input;
    this.output = output;
  }

  void ReadAndWrite() { 
    var data = input.Read();
    output.Write(data);
  }
}

[TestMethod]
public void ReadAndWriteShouldWriteSameObjectAsRead() {
  //we want to verify that SUT writes to the output interface
  //input is a stub, since we don't record any expectations
  Mock<IInput> input = new Mock<IInput>();
  //output is a mock, because we want to verify some behavior on it.
  Mock<IOutput> output = new Mock<IOutput>();

  var data = new object();
  input.Setup(i=>i.Read()).Returns(data);

  var sut = new SUT(input.Object, output.Object);
  //calling verify on a mock object makes the object a mock, with respect to method being verified.
  output.Verify(o=>o.Write(data));
}
```

In the above example I used Moq to demonstrate stubs and mocks. Moq uses the same class for both - `Mock<T>` which makes it a bit confusing. Regardless, at runtime, the test will fail if `output.Write` is not called with data as `parameter`, whereas failure to call `input.Read()` will not fail it.

Answer (score 4):

As another answer suggested via a link to "[Mocks Aren't Stubs](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#TheDifferenceBetweenMocksAndStubs)", mocks are a form of "test double" to use in lieu of a real object.  What makes them different from other forms of test doubles, such as stub objects, is that other test doubles offer state verification (and optionally simulation) whereas mocks offer behavior verification (and optionally simulation).

With a stub, you might call several methods on the stub in any order (or even repitiously) and determine success if the stub has captured a value or state you intended.  In contrast, a mock object expects very specific functions to be called, in a specific order, and even a specific number of times.  The test with a mock object will be considered "failed" simply because the methods were invoked in a different sequence or count - even if the mock object had the correct state when the test concluded!

In this way, mock objects are often considered more tightly coupled to the SUT code than stub objects.  That can be a good or bad thing, depending on what you are trying to verify.

Answer (score 3):

Part of the point of using mock objects is that they don't have to be really implemented according to spec. They can just give dummy responses. E.g. if you have to implement components A and B, and both "call" (interact with) each other, then you can't test A until B is implemented, and vice versa. In test-driven development, this is a problem. So you create mock ("dummy") objects for A and B, that are very simple, but they give *some* sort of response when they're interacted with. That way, you can implement and test A using a mock object for B.

Answer (score 1):

For php and phpunit is well explained in phpunit documentaion. see here
[phpunit documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects)

In simple word mocking object is just dummy object of your original one and is return its return value, this return value can be used in the test class

Answer (score 0):

It's one of the main perspectives of unit tests. yes, you're trying to test your single unit of code and your test results should not be relevant to other beans or objects behavior. so you should mock them by using Mock objects with some simplified corresponding response.