# Checking if function, tested with CMockery, calls another particular function

Tags: c, cmockery

I am facing problem in writing mock code using CMockery for a function shown below. Can you please give me some hint? I want to test if `startCalCompute` is called and also to assign value to `updateMode`, so that it is not equal to `SYSTEM_CAL_CONFIG`. All I need is a starting point or hint.

`foo.c`

```
static void checkSystem(void)
{
#ifndef CAL
    startCalCompute();
#endif

    if( SYSTEM_CAL_CONFIG != updateMode )
    {
        updateLogevent(); 
    }

    ...
}
```

`testfoo.c`

```
void Test_checkSystem( void ** state )
{   
    // what to do here to check if startCalCompute() is called ?
}
```

Comment: What if? What else? What is `will_return`?

Comment: I'm not sure CMockery can help you here; it looks like you're testing the `checkSystem()` function directly, not mocking its dependencies. Are there any effects (including side-effects) of the function that you can detect independently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to assign value to `updateMode` so that it is not equal to `SYSTEM_CAL_CONFIG`

If `updateMode` depends on value, which you get from another function and you want to control it during the test, then you should create a test double of that function. [Here is a good answer explaining mocks in particular.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3623574) If it is calculated entirely inside `checkSystem`, then test driver should not modify it, as its purpose is only to check the overall result.

`checkSystem.c`

```
/* checkSystem depends on a value returned by this function */
int getUpdateMode (void);

/* This function knows nothing about testing. It just does
   whatever it was created to do. */
void checkSystem (void)
{
    int updateMode = getUpdateMode ();
    if (SYSTEM_CAL_CONFIG != updateMode)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

`test_checkSystem.c`

```
/* When testing checkSystem, this function
   will be called instead of getUpdateMode */
int mock_getUpdateMode (void);
{
    /* Get a value from test driver */
    int updateMode = (int) mock();

    /* Return it to the tested function */
    return updateMode;
}

void test_checkSystem_caseUpdateMode_42 (void ** state)
{
    int updateMode = 42;       /* Pass a value to mock_getUpdateMode */
    will_return (mock_getUpdateMode, updateMode);

    checkSystem ();            /* Call the tested function */
    assert_int_equal (...);    /* Compare received result to expected */
}
```

> I want to test if `startCalCompute` is called

If `startCalCompute()` is conditionally compiled to be called by `checkSystem()`, then you could conditionally compile whatever you want to be done in tests:

```
void startCalCompute (void);
void checkSystem(void)
{
#ifdef CAL
    startCalCompute();
#endif
}

void test_checkSystem (void ** state)
{
#ifdef CAL
    ...
#endif
}
```

If you need to make sure that particular function was called and that depends on a runtime condition, or if some functions were called in a specific order, there are no tools in CMockery to do that. However, [there are](https://api.cmocka.org/group__cmocka__call__order.html) in [CMocka](https://cmocka.org/), which is a fork of CMockery and is quite similar. Here is how you would do that in CMocka:

`checkSystem.c`

```
void startCalCompute (void);
void checkSystem (void)
{
    if (...)
        startCalCompute ();
}
```

`test_checkSystem.c`

```
/* When testing checkSystem, this function
   will be called instead of startCalCompute */
void __wrap_startCalCompute (void)
{
    /* Register the function call */
    function_called ();
}

void test_checkSystem (void ** status)
{
    expect_function_call (__wrap_startCalCompute);
    checkSystem ();
}
```

Now if `checkSystem` will not call `startCalCompute`, the test will fail like this:

```
[==========] Running 1 test(s).
[ RUN      ] test_checkSystem
[  ERROR   ] --- __wrap_startCalCompute function was expected to be called but was not.
test_checkSystem.c:1: note: remaining item was declared here

[  FAILED  ] test_checkSystem
[==========] 1 test(s) run.
[  PASSED  ] 0 test(s).
[  FAILED  ] 1 test(s), listed below:
[  FAILED  ] test_checkSystem
```

Comment: thanks mate thats quite helpful. just one doubt     assert_int_equal (...);    /* Compare received result to expected */ what I need to compare here . One value is updateMode which I received from mock function.What will be other value? Since checkSystem return void how would i compare updateMode from inside that function?

Comment: @samprat Well, if you the only thing you want to check is that your function calls another function, then you don't need this assertion. But generally, if you test a function, you want to make sure it produces the right result, not just calls another one. If `checkSystem` would return or change variable, that is where you would check if it did it right.

Comment: @samprat I would recommend checking out the `cmocka` manuals instead of those you get for `cmockery` from Google. They are much clearer and easier to understand, and most of the stuff you can do in `cmockery` in the exact same way, since these two frameworks share the same code base. And after all, maybe you don't even need a unit testing framework for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sergey B for help.