# Django: Class object has no attribute of standard function

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have a model:

```
class Order(models.Model):

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (100, 'First'),
        (200, 'Second'),
    )
    status = models.IntegerField('Status', choices=STATUS_CHOICES)

    def accept(self):
        self.status = 200
        self.save()
        return self.status, self.get_status_display()
```

And I have a Unit-Test for it:

```
class CustomTestCase(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def save(self):
        pass


class OrderTest(CustomTestCase):

    def test_accept(self):
        result = Order.accept(self)
        expected = (200, 'Second')

        self.assertEqual(expected, result)
```

As you can see, i added 'save' function that do nothing, the reason for that is because without that custom 'save' function I keep getting this error:

> [OrderTest] object has no attribute [save]

If there is a better solution to that custom 'save' function please tell me. But this kind of solution will not work with django-built-in 'get_status_display()' function. And without solution I keep getting this trouble:

> [OrderTest] object has no attribute [get_status_display]

What can I do to make this work as I need ?

Comment: Should self be passed to the accept function ? Oder.accept() ?

Comment: In that case, I got: "TypeError: accept() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to test the `accept` method, just create a new Order like this:

```
 def test_accept(self):
    order = Order.objects.create(status=100)
    result = order.accept()
    expected = (200, 'Second')
    self.assertEqual(expected, result)
```

The reason why you got the `[OrderTest] object has no attribute [save]` error is you pass the test object into the `accept` method (in "`Order.accept(self)`"), so when `self.save()` is called, it actually looks for the `save` method of the test class.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I do not understand one thing, what is a purpose of mocking, if I have to actually create objects for testing ? For example I tried to do this: order = Mock(spec=Order) and it did not work, however: order = Order.objects.create(status=100) worked perfectly. If I have to create new objects via 'Model.objects.create' for every unit-test, why even use mocking ?

Comment: @Madi7 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622455/what-is-the-purpose-of-mock-objects