# mockito mock verify

Tags: java, mockito

```
//Let's import Mockito statically so that the code looks clearer
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

//mock creation
List mockedList = mock(List.class);

//using mock object
mockedList.add("one");
mockedList.clear();

//verification
verify(mockedList).add("one");
verify(mockedList).clear();
```

I don't understand what is the point of this construct? How does it help? How is it different from just calling the functions?
The documentation is rather thin.
Thank you

Comment: You're basically asking "My would I ever want to mock classes in testing", which google can surely help you with. Also: http://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/FeaturesAndMotivations

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is Mocking?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665812/what-is-mocking)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wish to test that some method `Foo` of class A calls some method `Bar` on an object of class B.  In other words, you're testing class A.  During your test, you make a mock of class B.  Then you pass this mock object to class A somehow (depending on how class A actually works).  When your test runs the `Foo` method of class A, you are expecting the `Bar` method to get called on your mock of class B.  By calling `verify` for the `Bar` method, after the test of the `Foo` method, you can check that the `Foo` method is actually working correctly - that it calls `Bar`.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `mockedList.add("one");` its performing the operation on the `mocked object` as same time it remembers your operation. So when you do `verify(mockedList).add("one");`, it verifies the `add` was called on `mockedList` with argument `one`.

Hope you get the difference.

Comment: what could I discover by doing this? I still don't see a practical example

Comment: @titus This is a simple example. Think of a scenario when you passed this object to some custom method. Now you want to verify, one particular method on that object was called or no. This will lbe useful.  Also another difference is to use your mock object for stubbing, which becomes very important when you are dealing with objects, which are not available in your test environment. You can simply mock and stub them. Once called, mockito will use the stubbed behavior.

Answer (score 1):

the verify method of mockito is verify the method invoke times,if the invoke time is 1,we can omit this parameter, see the source code of Mockito Line 1473

```
public static <T> T verify(T mock) {
    return MOCKITO_CORE.verify(mock, times(1));
}
```

so you code

```
verify(mockedList).add("one");
//is the same as
verify(mockedList,times(1)).add("one");
```

is indeed to verify the add method's executed once

Answer (score 0):

Indeed in your example it's obvious, but main idea of verifying methods calls appear during  real code testing - imagine that some code performs method call like:

```
class A{
 ....
 service.doSomething(<some arguments>)
 ....
}
```

In order to test it you'll pass mock service object, but sometimes you want to verify particular arguments values passed for that call (or number of calls), so you'll use verify like in your example.