# How do you create a proper unit test for a method that returns a list?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I have this method:

```
public DataSourceResult GetProjectBySpec(int projectId, int seasonId, int episodeId)
        {
            using (var rep = RepositoryHelper.GetTake2Repository<ITake2RepositoryBase>())
            {
                var spec = new ProjectCrewsByProjectSpec(projectId, seasonId, episodeId);

                var personList = rep.GetList<ProjectDGACrew>(spec).Select(p => new
                {
                    //big query...
                    .ToDataSourceResult();

                return personList;
            }
        }
```

I need to create a unit test for this.

My first question is:

1. What am I testing for? Am I ONLY testing to see if the method returns a list?
2. If so, how would I go about testing it?

This is what I have so far:

```
    [TestClass]
    public class CrewControllerTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void GetProjectCrewsBySpecTest()
        {
            // arrange
            int projectId = 1;
            int seasonId = 2;
            int episodeId = 3;

            // act
            var crewController = new CrewController();
            DataSourceResult dsr = crewController.GetProjectCrewsBySpec(1, 2, 3);

            // assert
            // what or how do I assert here? Am I just checking whether "dsr" is a list? How do I do that?
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm a unit-testing noob as well, but my assumption is that you already know what you *should* be getting back from the method when you enter those inputs. Compare that with what you *actually* get back to determine if the unit test is successful.

Comment: so basically testing for a query is worthless no? since the data can change all the time.

Comment: If that's the case, you might have to mock up the database in order to get reliable returns every time. Since I'm not positive, I'll just +1 your question and wait for someone more knowledgeable to weigh in. :)

Comment: thanks! just starting to learn how to do unit testing so I need some help lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm no expert either,and I've only been doing TDD for a small while so take what I write in this rambling answer with a spoonful of salt :) I am sure someone else can point out if I've made any really bad mistakes or pointed you in the wrong direction...

I'm not sure your test is really a Unit Test because it's exercising multiple dependencies. Suppose for a moment that you run this test and get an exception thrown out of the method.
Did this exception come from

- RepositoryHelper.GetTake2Repository())
  throwing? (Depencency issue)
- ProjectCrewsByProjectSpec constructor throwing? (Dependency issue)
- rep.GetList(spec) throwing? the kendo (it is
  kendo,right?) (Dependency issue)
- ToDataSourceResult() throwing? (Behavioural issue)

Unit testing is all about testing things in complete isolation from their dependencies, so at the moment I'd say it's more like an integration test whereby you don't really care *how* the systems interact, you just want to make sure that for a given projectID, seasonId and episodeId you get back the expected results - in this case what are *really* testing is the **rep.GetList()** method in conjunction with the .**ToDataSourceResult** extension.

Now integration tests are very very useful and 100% required as part of a test driven methodology,and if that's what you really want to do, then you're doing it about right.(I put *this* in and expect *that* back; did I get *that* back?)

But if you want to *Unit Test* this code (specifically, if you want to unit test your classes' **GetProjectBySpec** method) you will have to do as @jimmy_keen mentioned and refactor it so that you can test the *behaviour* of GetProjectBySpec.
e.g. here is a specified behaviour I just invented, of course yours might be different:

- If input is bad, throw ArgumentException
- Creates a new   ProjectCrewsByProjectSpec object
- Calls rep.GetList and passes spec to it
- Returns a non-null DataSourceResult

The first thing you need to do in order to be able to test that GetProjectBySpec does all of the things in the above list is to refactor it so that it doesn't create its own dependencies - instead, you give it the dependencies it needs, via [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

DI really works best when you are injecting by Interface, so in whatever class provides this method, your constructor for that class should take an instance of for example **IRepositoryHelper** and store it in a private readonly member. It should also take an instance of **IProjectCrewsByProjectSpecFactory** which you'd use to create your spec. Now since you want to test what GetProjectBySpec actually *does* with these dependencies then you'll be using a mocking framework such as [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart) which I won't go into here except in the example below.

If neither of these classes currently implement such an interface, then just use Visual Studio to extract the interface definition for you based on the class definition. If they are 3rd party classes over which you have no control, this might be tricky.

But let's assume for a minute that you can define interfaces thus: (bear with me on the generic <> bits which I'm never 100% on, I am sure someone smarter than me can tell you where all the "T"'s should go...) Code below is not tested nor checked for typos!

```
public interface IRepositoryHelper<ProjectDGACrew>
{
  IList<ProjectDGACrew> GetList(IProjectCrewsByProjectSpecFactory spec);
}

public interface IProjectCrewsByProjectSpecFactory 
{
 ProjectDGACrew Create(int projectId, int seasonId, int episodeId);
}
```

Your code would then end up looking something like this:

```
//somewhere in your class definition
private readonly IRepositoryHelper<T> repo;
private readonly IProjectCrewsByProjectSpecFactory pfactory;
//constructor
public MyClass(IRepositoryHelper<ProjectDGACrew> repo, IProjectCrewsByProjectSpecFactory pfactory)
{
this.repo = repo;
this.pfactory=pfactory;
}
//method to be tested
public DataSourceResult GetProjectBySpec(int projectId, int seasonId, int episodeId)
{
            var spec = pfactory.Create(projectId, seasonId, episodeId);
            var personList = repo.GetList(spec).Select(p => new
                {//big query...}).ToDataSourceResult();
                return personList;
}
```

now you have 4 test methods to write:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExepctedException(typeof(ArgumentException)]
public void SUT_WhenInputIsBad_ThrowsArgumentException()
{
    var sut = new MyClass(null,null); //don't care about our dependencies for this check
    sut.GetProjectBySpec(0,0,0); //or whatever is invalid input for you.
    //don't care about the return, only that the method throws.
}



[TestMethod]
public void SUT_WhenInputIsGood_CreatesProjectCrewsByProjectSpec()
{
  //create dependencies using Moq framework.
  var pf= new Mock<IProjectCrewsByProjectSpecFactory>();
  var repo = new Mock<IRepository<ProjectDgaCrew>>();
  //setup such that a call to pfactory.Create in the tested method will return nothing
  //because we actually don't care about the result - only that the Create method is called.
  pf.Setup(p=>p.Create(1,2,3)).Returns<ProjectDgaCrew>(new ProjectDgaCrew());
  //setup the repo such that any call to GetList with any ProjectDgaCrew object returns an empty list
//again we do not care about the result. 
//This mock dependency is only being used here
//to stop an exception being thrown from the test method
//you might want to refactor your behaviours
//to specify an early exit from the function when the factory returns a null object for example.
   repo.Setup(r=>r.GetList(It.IsAny<ProjectDgaCrew>()).Returns<IList<ProjectDGACrew>>(new List<ProjectDgaCrew>());
  //create our System under test, inject our mock objects:
   var sut = new MyClass(repo,pf.Object);
   //call the method:
   sut.GetProjectBySpec(1,2,3);
   //and verify that it did indeed call the factory.Create method.
    pf.Verify(p=>p.Create(1,2,3),"pf.Create was not called with 1,2,3");              
}
        public void SUT_WhenInputIsGood_CallsRepoGetList(){} //you get the idea
        public void SUT_WhenInputIsGood_ReturnsNonNullDataSourceResult(){}//and so on.
```

Hope that gives you some help...and of course you can refactor your test classes to avoid a lot of the mocking setup and have it all in a single place to keep the lines of code to a minimum.

Answer (score 3):

Unit tests usually (should) test contract as understood by class client. When client of your code calls `.GetProjectBySpec(1, 2, 3)`, what is he expecting to happen? Unit test should *answer* this question:

> When there's 5 projects in repository (*A*, *B*, *C*, *D*, *E*) and I call `GetProjectBySpec` with parameters *1*, *2*, *3*, I should get projects ***B*** and ***C***

In your case it might depend on what's being done in `//big query...` part. If it's *filtering/transformation* of the results returned from repository, this is what you should test for.

Note that you'll probably need to change few things in order to make this test isolated (from repository/database):

- `RepositoryHelper.GetTake2Repository` should be wrapped in interface, [**injected**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/130794/343266) as dependency and [**mocked**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665812/what-is-mocking) later in unit test
- if `new ProjectCrewsByProjectSpec` creates complex object, you might want to use [**factory**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) instead

When you'll have repository mocked, you simply instruct your mock to return some upfront known list of items when it's called with matching `spec` parameter. Then your unit test can verify whether data returned from `GetProjectBySpec` meets your expectations.

Answer (score 1):

I write tests this way:

1. Write a test for each path through the code.
2. Write a test for boundary conditions. Such as: zero, one, or two items in your list. Bad parameters, etc.
3. Write negative tests. These are hardest since you can write an infinite number of useless tests. A good example is checking that things that should not be changed aren't changed.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

This is more simpler way by which you can test data inside it as well. Modifying from where you left.

```
[TestClass]
    public class CrewControllerTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void GetProjectCrewsBySpecTest()
        {
          // arrange
          const String ExpectedOutput = "";
          int projectId = 1;
          int seasonId = 2;
          int episodeId = 3;

          // act
          var crewController = new CrewController();
          var resultList= crewController.GetProjectCrewsBySpec(1, 2,3) as DataSourceResult;
          var someInsideData = resultlist.FirstOrDefault().GetType().GetProperty("PropertyName").GetValue(resultList.FirstOrDefault(),null);

          // assert
          Assert.AreEqual(someInsideData , ExpectedOutput);          
        }
}
```