# Need to choose assertion for unit test?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

This is my code:

```
public int GetTotalIssuedCount()
{
    var storeCode = Store.Current.Code.ToLower();
    return (from i in Context.Instance.EduContainer.IssueDetailsSet
            where i.Status.ToLower() == "issued" && i.Store.Code == storeCode
            select i).Count();
}
```

This is my test code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetTotalIssuedCountTest()
{
    StoreRepository sr = new StoreRepository();
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType();
}
```

Which assert method will be appropriate here?

Comment: Please provide more information about what your method does and what Unit Test should check? It depends on your requirements - which assertion to use.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assert whether count matches what you expect, given underlying data set state:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetTotalIssuedCountTest()
{
   // The 5 is exemplary value -
   // you need to determine actual one basing data set contents
   const int expectedIssuedCount = 5;
   var storeRepository = new StoreRepository();
   // Here you'll most likely need to prepare fake data set
   var actualIssuedCount = storeRepository.GetTotalIssuedCount();

   Assert.AreEqual(expectedIssuedCount, actualIssuedCount);
}
```

To make it work you need to set *fake* data set (`EduContainer.IssueDetailsSet`) which your method will access. You'll most likely need [**mocks**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2665812/343266) together with [**dependency injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/130794/343266) to achieve that.

Comment: I have to point out (Since Jon Skeet did to me one time :)) that generally, the assertion signatures are `(expected, actual)`, not `(actual, expected)`.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: this is indeed true for MSTest (which I assume OP is using). Thanks.