# Testing contacts in android

Tags: android, testing, android-manifest, android-contacts

I have a class that filters contacts by name, email, or phone. 
I wrote a test for this class that uses target context and is able to test the functionality properly.

```
public class ContactsManagerTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        mContext = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
        mContactsManager = new ContactsManager(mContext);
    }

    public void testFilterWhenQueryMatchEmail() {
        List<SearchableContact> contacts = mContactsManager.filter("john.smith@gmail.com");
        Assert.assertFalse(contacts.isEmpty());
    }
}
```

Now this works, problem is that the test relies on contacts present in my phone, so if someone else run this test it will fail.

What I want to do is to have the test populate contacts at the setUp method and then use those to test the `ContactsManager`. 
However, I don't know want the test to put garbage contacts on my phone.

Is there some way to have the test run on a separate context where I can populate contacts without having them added to my phone?

What I tried to do is change the `setUp`method to to use the regular context instead of the target context, like so:

```
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        mContext = getInstrumentation().getContext();
        mContactsManager = new ContactsManager(mContext);
    }
```

However then I get the following error: `com.example.ifeins.sandbox.test from uid 10082 not allowed to perform READ_CONTACTS`.

I tried adding an AndroidManifest.xml file to `app/src/androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml` with the `READ_CONTACTS` permission but it had no effect.

Thanks,
Ido

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you only want to test the filter function.

If that is the case, you should use a Mock class to represent the mContext. And populate the values in it using your setup function.

If you don't know what Mocking is: [What is Mocking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665812/what-is-mocking)

Comment: I rather do an integration test that will give me more confidence that my class works properly.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, this might not be what you are looking for, but
have you checked out:

http://selendroid.io/

https://code.google.com/p/robotium/

I haven't tried these out before, but I did try selenium for web applications which seemed to have worked fine.