# How to unit test an Angular component that is making GET call using a service

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

This question here:
[How to unit test a component that calls observable service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36848466/how-to-unit-test-a-component-that-calls-observable-service) has an accepted answer. But I don't want to test the service right now. I've some articles stored on a server. I've a component `ArticlesComponent` which uses `ArticlesService` to fetch all those articles. Today I want to test `ArticlesComponent` only. Here is the code.

**articles.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ArticleService } from '../article.service';
...


@Component({
  ...
})
export class ArticlesComponent implements OnInit {

  articles = [];
  filteredArticles=[];

  constructor(private _articleService: ArticleService) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllArticles();
  }

  getAllArticles() {
    this._articleService.getEvents()
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.articles = res,
        this.filteredArticles = res},
      err => console.log(err)
    )
  }
}
```

When `ngOnInit` gets called then it calls `getAllArticles` along with it. Here is the spec file which is failing.

**articles.component.spec.ts**

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
...
import { ArticlesComponent } from './articles.component';

fdescribe('ArticlesComponent', () => {
  let component: ArticlesComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ArticlesComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ArticlesComponent],
      imports: [
       ...
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ArticlesComponent);
    component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  /* THIS CASE IS FAILING*/
  it('should call ngOnInit', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ArticlesComponent);
    const component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    let spy_getAllArticles = spyOn(component,"getAllArticles").and.returnValue([]);
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(component.filteredArticles).toEqual([]);
  })
});
```

Why it is failing, complaining that method doesn't exists:

[image]

Comment: The mentioned question with an accepted answer at the beginning contains the right approach. It does not contain the testing of the service itself but mocking the service for the component test. A mock object needs to be created for the service and it needs to be provided in the tested component.

Comment: @MilanTenk, I'm following this : https://codehandbook.org/how-to-unit-test-angular-component-with-service/

Comment: @MilanTenk, but still it should not show "message not found". It is there, we all can see it. Please explain this.

Comment: Hm.. Yes it is strange that the `getAllArticles()` method is not found. I spotted that there is a global `let component: ArticlesComponent;`, it is assigned in `beforeEach` and in the `it` there is a `const component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;` where the `component` variable has the same name as the global one.
Could you please try to remove this redundant variable?
I think the global one is fine, because in the `beforeEach` it is assigned with the right value.

Comment: Is `article.component.ts` or `articles.component.ts`?

Comment: @slideshowp2, it is `articles`. Edited the question also.

Comment: @Tanzeel: There are few suggestions that I would make but first I would like to address the main issue. Can you confirm that `getAllArticles` is not `private` ? Also , can u try putting `console.log(component.getAllArticles)` in spec file ? See if you are able to access the method. If not `log` the `component` object and see which component does it belong to

Comment: @ShashankVivek, If I remember you've written some articles on Unit testing in angular. Please share that link I would like to go through it again.

Comment: @Tanzeel: There you go : https://shashankvivek-7.medium.com/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49 .