# requests-like wrapper for flask's test_client

Tags: python, python-requests, werkzeug

I'm trying to make a usable tests for my package, but using `Flask.test_client` is so different from the `requests` API that I found it hard to use.

I have tried to make `requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter` wrap the response, but it looks like `werkzeug` doesn't use `httplib` (or `urllib` for that matter) to build it own `Response` object.

Any idea how it can be done? Reference to existing code will be the best (googling werkzeug + requests doesn't give any useful results)

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

A PyPI package now exists for this so you can use `pip install requests-flask-adapter`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood what you need is a **mocking** (see [What is Mocking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665812/what-is-mocking) and [Mock Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object)). Well, couple of your options listed below:

- If you are going to mock only requests package use [requests-mock library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-mock) which intended to mock out responses from the requests package.
- Another option is to use python [**mock libary**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) to mock `requests` module, also see [An Introduction to Mocking in Python](https://www.toptal.com/python/an-introduction-to-mocking-in-python)
  .

Comment: thanks, but I want adapter, not a mock. creating a middleware which translates `Flask.test_client` to `requests_mock` sounds an overhead over just creating `requests.Adapter`

Comment: For anyone who does want that middleware, there is a PyPI package which provides it: https://pypi.org/project/requests-mock-flask.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `requests` method defined in the code section below. 
To use it you'll also need to define the `get_auth_headers` method shown in the code below.

**Features:**

- Wrapper around the Flask test client.
- Automatically set the request headers.

  - `Content-Type: Application/json` when passing `json`
  - `Basic Authentication` constructed when passing `auth`.
- Dumps your `json` data as a string to the Flask test client.
- (Missing) Wrap the response into a `requests.Response` object

**Code:**

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app('testing')
        self.client = self.app.test_client()
        self.app_context = self.app.app_context()
        self.app_context.push()
        db.create_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()
        self.app_context.pop()

    def get_auth_headers(self, username, password):
        return {
            'Authorization':
                'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(
                    (username + ':' + password).encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8'),
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

    def requests(self, method, url, json={}, auth=(), **kwargs):
        """Wrapper around Flask test client to automatically set headers if JSON
        data is passed + dump JSON data as string."""
        if not hasattr(self.client, method):
            print("Method %s not supported" % method)
            return
        fun = getattr(self.client, method)

        # Set headers
        headers = {}
        if auth:
            username, password = auth
            headers = self.get_auth_headers(username, password)

        # Prepare JSON if needed
        if json:
            import json as _json
            headers.update({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
            response = fun(url,
                           data=_json.dumps(json),
                           headers=headers,
                           **kwargs)
        else:
            response = fun(url, **kwargs)
        self.assertTrue(response.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json')
        return response
```

**Usage (in a test case):**

```
def test_requests(self):
    url = 'http://localhost:5001'
    response = self.requests('get', url)
    response = self.requests('post', url, json={'a': 1, 'b': 2}, auth=('username', 'password'))
    ...
```

The only difference with `requests` is that instead of typing `requests.get(...)` you'll have to type `self.request('get', ...)`.

If you really want `requests` behaviour, you'll need to define your own `get`, `put`, `post`, `delete` wrappers around `requests`

**Note:**

An optimal way to do this might be to subclass `FlaskClient` as described in [Flask API documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.Flask.test_client)