# How can I do unit testing in an XPage page, without access to the server?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, xpages

I need to have some kind of unit testing in my current XPage project. Problem is that I do not have access to the server so I can not install testing frameworks onto the server. I can only access the application from the Notes Designer and get all files from the git repository.

How can I implement unit testing under these conditions?

Comment: What is your framework?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 suggestions:

- Whatever response your server is to return, can't you just [stub/mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665812/what-is-mocking/40244095#40244095) them?
- Can't you just create a dummy server and then have another target in your application which you change the basepath of its endPoint/URLS and on the dummy server/subdomain install whatever framework you need?

change:

```
https://Curunir.com/users/
```

to:

```
https://Dummy.Curunir.com/users/
```

Answer (score 0):

On OpenNTF is JUnit project for XPages, created by Christian Gudemann, https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/org.openntf.junit.xsp

I did a basic test, it worked ;-)