# How to mock function in go?

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type SessionInterface1 interface {
    doLoginAndReadDestinations1() bool
}

type Session1 struct {
    sessionCookie string
    mux           sync.Mutex
    sessionTime   time.Time
    targetAddress string
    currentJwt    string
    transport     *http.Transport
}

var currentSession1 Session1

func main() {

    currentSession1.verifyLogin1()

}

func (s *Session1) doLoginAndReadDestinations1() bool {
    ..logic...
    ... for example return true

}

func callDest1(si SessionInterface1) bool {
    return si.doLoginAndReadDestinations1()
}

func (s *Session1) verifyLogin1() bool {
    return callDest1(s)
}
```

I want to create unit test and to mock doLoginAndReadDestinations1
I tried to create interface for this method and I create test

```
func test1(t *testing.T) {
    type args struct {
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name string
        args args
        want bool
    }{{
        name: "test",
        args: args{},
        want: false,
    }}
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            var s1 *Session1
            count := 10
            s1 = &Session1{"", sync.Mutex{}, time.Now(), "", "", nil}

            var got1 = s1.verifyLogin()

            if got1 != tt.want {
                t.Errorf("getJwt() = %v, want %v", got, tt.want)
            }

        })
    }
}
```

I didn't know how I can change the logic of function doLoginAndReadDestinations1 in the test and to change the logic in the first main

Comment: It looks like your posted code is the mock, so it's not really clear what your question is about it.

Comment: I want to do mock for this function doLoginAndReadDestinations1 in the test How I can do it ?

Comment: Is the one posted not a mock? The one that's just `return true`?

Comment: it is just an example the idea that there is any logic there , I will update it

Comment: The verifyLogin on Session is called to doLoginAndReadDestinations1 that have complex logic with HTTP call and more logic and I in my test I just want that this method will return true,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to abstract everything you want to mock. Instead of resolving  dependency as a concrete implementation, use an interface. Then you will be able to create a mock which will implement this interface.

Generally, I would suggest you [stretchr/testify](https://github.com/stretchr/testify) for testing. It has methods for :

1. assert
2. require
3. **mock**
4. suite

This library will help you structuring test, writing tests and remove your boilerplate code. **It has mocking mechanisms inside**. Read about mocking interfaces at [testify mock section](https://github.com/stretchr/testify)

Comment: but I create interface for this method type SessionInterface1 interface {
    doLoginAndReadDestinations1() bool
}

Comment: Do I need to change my implementation ? if yes what do you suggest ?

Comment: and I want to mock doLoginAndReadDestinations1 in my case

Comment: can I use  stretchr/testify in my real code or I need to change it ?

Answer (score 2):

In your unit test, you're only calling methods on `Session1`, not on something that *calls* `Session1`'s methods; so there isn't anything to mock. When using mocking for tests, you don't mock *methods*, you mock *types*, when those types are *dependencies* of the type under test. For example, if you have a type `Foo` which depends on (calls methods of) a type `Bar`, and you want to test `Foo` in isolation, you would create a mock of type `Bar`, and in your tests for `Foo`, you'd give it your `BarMock` instead of `Bar`. In your real code, you'd give it the real `Bar`. There is no way to mock a single method of a type.

You might find [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665812/what-is-mocking) and its extensive answers helpful.

Comment: The idea that Call to method verifyLogin that call to callDest1 that it is interface of doLoginAndReadDestinations1 I want to mock this function and not to call to the real one. do I need to change the real code ? if yes how ?

Comment: My problem that I want to write test that will not do the logic of doLoginAndReadDestinations1 in the verifyLogin  test

Comment: Again, *you cannot mock a method, you can only mock a type*. If you want to mock only that function, you need to move it to a new type, create an interface, add a field to the original type, and fill that new field with your mock implementation in your tests and the real implementation in your production code.

Comment: sorry I am not expert in this could you give me an example How I need to do it ?

Comment: could we have a short chat ?

Comment: type SessionInterface1 interface {
 doLoginAndReadDestinations1() bool
} is a new type with interface