# How can I mock Date and Now?

Tags: delphi

Some of my code use Date and Now. So the result for tests on that code is different depending on when it execute. That is of course bad.
So what is the recommended way of fake Date and Time in tests ?

Using interface ?

Comment: @Dima https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665812/what-is-mocking

Comment: @Roland You can't easily mock `Date` and `Now`. So change your code to call your own library functions to obtain the current date and time. Implement those functions in a way to allow them to be mocked.

Comment: You could hook them but then they are globally changed and nobody knows where that might break something.

Comment: Mocking aside, Fwiw if I'm testing date-dependent code, I tend to use the 29th of February in a leap-year.  If we all did that we would have been spared all the y2k hype.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thank you! Useful link!

Answer (score 4):

In order to make things testable you need to have or create [seams](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=359417&seqNum=2) in your code.

You might want to use the Ambient Context design pattern to achieve this in this particular example. While this looks like a singleton at first it actually allows temporarily replacing the used instance or the returned data. The following is an example how to implement it in Delphi based on [this blog post](https://codopia.wordpress.com/2017/04/24/how-to-mock-up-datetime-now-in-unit-tests-using-ambient-context-pattern/).

I left out the thread safety and all that stuff to give you the basic idea how it works. You might also get rid of TDateTimeProvider singleton/class altogether and just make your own `Now` function that works with mocking.

```
program AmbientContextDemo;

uses
  Generics.Collections,
  TestFramework,
  TestInsight.DUnit,
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TDateTimeProvider = class
  strict private
    class var fInstance: TDateTimeProvider;
    class function GetInstance: TDateTimeProvider; static;
  public
    function Now: TDateTime;
    class property Instance: TDateTimeProvider read GetInstance;
  end;

  TDateTimeProviderContext = class
  strict private
    var fContextNow: TDateTime;
    class var contextStack: TStack<TDateTimeProviderContext>;
    class function GetCurrent: TDateTimeProviderContext; static;
  public
    class constructor Create;
    class destructor Destroy;

    constructor Create(const contextNow: TDateTime);
    destructor Destroy; override;

    property ContextNow: TDateTime read fContextNow;
    class property Current: TDateTimeProviderContext read GetCurrent;
  end;

  TStuff = class
    // class procedure for demo purpose, no instance necessary in test
    class function DoSomeDateTimeStuff_UsingNow: TDateTime;
    class function DoSomeDateTimeStuff_UsingAmbientContext: TDateTime;
  end;

  TMyTest = class(TTestCase)
  published
    procedure TestIt_Fail;
    procedure TestIt_Pass;
  end;

{ TDateTimeProvider }

class function TDateTimeProvider.GetInstance: TDateTimeProvider;
begin
  if not Assigned(fInstance) then
    fInstance := TDateTimeProvider.Create;
  Result := fInstance;
end;

function TDateTimeProvider.Now: TDateTime;
var
  context: TDateTimeProviderContext;
begin
  context := TDateTimeProviderContext.Current;
  if Assigned(context) then
    Result := context.ContextNow
  else
    Result := System.SysUtils.Now;
end;

{ TMyTest }

procedure TMyTest.TestIt_Fail;
begin
  CheckEquals(EncodeDate(2018, 11, 11), TStuff.DoSomeDateTimeStuff_UsingNow);
end;

procedure TMyTest.TestIt_Pass;
var
  ctx: TDateTimeProviderContext;
begin
  ctx := TDateTimeProviderContext.Create(EncodeDate(2018, 11, 11));
  try
    CheckEquals(EncodeDate(2018, 11, 11), TStuff.DoSomeDateTimeStuff_UsingAmbientContext);
  finally
    ctx.Free;
  end;
end;

{ TStuff }

class function TStuff.DoSomeDateTimeStuff_UsingNow: TDateTime;
begin
  Result := Now; // using Now which is unmockable, only via hooking but that affects all occurences even in the RTL
end;

class function TStuff.DoSomeDateTimeStuff_UsingAmbientContext: TDateTime;
begin
  Result := TDateTimeProvider.Instance.Now;
end;

{ TDateTimeProviderContext }

class constructor TDateTimeProviderContext.Create;
begin
  contextStack := TStack<TDateTimeProviderContext>.Create;
end;

class destructor TDateTimeProviderContext.Destroy;
begin
  contextStack.Free;
end;

constructor TDateTimeProviderContext.Create(const contextNow: TDateTime);
begin
  fContextNow := contextNow;
  contextStack.Push(Self);
end;

destructor TDateTimeProviderContext.Destroy;
begin
  contextStack.Pop;
end;

class function TDateTimeProviderContext.GetCurrent: TDateTimeProviderContext;
begin
  if contextStack.Count = 0 then
    Result := nil
  else
    Result := contextStack.Peek;
end;

begin
  RegisterTest(TMyTest.Suite);
  RunRegisteredTests;
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

It's mentioned above, but some example code may help.  Here's a method I've been using for 20 years.  Implement methods to replace `Date` and `Now` functions with your own that allow an override, then replace all references in your code to utilize the replacements.  When you need to test, simply set TestDate to a value appropriate for your tests.

```
var
  TestDate: TDateTime = 0;

function CurrDate: TDateTime;
begin
  if TestDate = 0 then
    Result := SysUtils.Date
  else
    Result := TestDate;
end;

function CurrDateTime: TDateTime;
begin
  if (TestDate = 0) then
    Result := Now
  else 
    Result := TestDate + Time;
end;
```

Comment: This is roughly how I do it. But I have a boolean variable instead (like `FixedTestDateTime: boolean`) and a fixed test datetime (which also includes a fixed time of the day).

Comment: Ad hoc manual mocking doesn't scale. Use a mocking library. -1

Comment: My use extended beyond testing and allowed using a fixed sample database for sales demo purpose.  The app was very focused on daily activity and allowing sales to fix the date based on their sample data worked well.

Comment: @RandySill That's nice. The question is about mocking for unit tests though.

Answer (score 1):

Consider you call `Date()` and `Now()` without unit prefix like `SysUtils.Date()`. Then add `MyTestUtils.pas` unit to the end of `uses` with conditional compiling

```
{$IFDEF TestMode}
, MyTestUtils
{$ENDIF}
```

In `MyTestUtils.pas` you can define your own `Date()` and `Now()` functions that will be used instead of `SysUtils` ones.

However it's a "nasty hack" that normally doesn't work when a good programmer uses unit prefixes to call functions.

Comment: Yes, a bad idea, brittle, not scalable, -1

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thank you, cap obvious ;) It is written in the answer.

Comment: It's a strange way to approach answering questions, writing a low quality answer and including a disclaimer to that effect in the text of the answer.