# Unit Test with Mock and Multiple Functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I cannot instantiate an object because it is an abstract class, so I have to use mocking in order to test my code.

I have been told this is best done by creating a new `mock` class.

```
class MockMyClass(MyClass):
    def my_first_function(...):
```

The idea is that I then instantiate a `MockMyClass` object, where I can test private function in that.

---

I have read the python [guide](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) and researched other stack [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665812/what-is-mocking). Here, the theory behind mock has been well explained. Unfortunately, I am still lost with how mocking can be used in a large unittest for multiple functions. For instance:

If I have a class, from which other classes in the main code inherit functions from. This can take the form:

```
class SharedFunctions(AnotherClass):
    first_function():
        #do some important calculations to generate stuff.#
        self.stuff = first_function_attribute_stuff

        return returned_first_stuff

    second_functions(returned_stuff)
        returned_second_stuff = self.stuff + returned_first_stuff
        
        return returned_second_stuff
```

and where the class `SharedFunctions` also inherits from another class (noting the abstract method) of the form:

```
class AnotherClass():
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def one_important_universal_function(...):
        pass
```

I have tried to construct a `unittest` for the `SharedFunctions` piece of code.

---

This is what I have tried so far:

```
class MockSharedFunctions(SharedFunctions):
    def first_function(...):
        self.stuff = some value
        returned_first_stuff = given some other value

        return returned_first_stuff

    def second_function
        returned_second_stuff = another value.

        return returned_second_stuff

class TestSharedFunctions(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_first_function(self):
        # insert code #

        self.assertTrue(True)

    def test_second_function(self):
        # insert code #

        self.assetEqual(output, expected)
        self.assertTrue(True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Where `insert code` has been a number of various attempts to use mocking. However, I have not come across a clear example of how mock functions can be used to replace other functions, or a confirmation that this will work.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Did you have a look at `mock.patch`? Basically, you have to replace all objects you don't want to call in the test with mock objects (using `patch`), and configure these if needed. Your example code is very abstract, so it is not clear what you actually want to test - it would help to put a more concrete example here (instead of just `assert True`) to understand what are you going to test.

Comment: Thank you @MrBeanBremen. I had looked at the youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYkGguhdqw0 which showed the usage of patches. However, I couldnt see how this would apply to my case. Also, thank you pointing out that my question is a bit too generic. I was hoping this would help for other users, I will try and make it more specific when I get a spare moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common issue is too over complicate the use of mocking functions. You can almost treat them like another class method. In your case, the `abstractmethod` decorator is probably generating the confusion.

This is something close to what you might need.

```
class MockSharedFunctions(SharedFunctions):
    def one_important_universal_function(**args):
        return 0

class TestSharedFunctions(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_first_function(self):
        mock = MockSharedFunctions()
        mock_output = firstfunction(**args)
        mock_stuff = mock.stuff

        self.assertTrue(True)
        self.assetEqual(mock_output, expected)
        self.assetEqual(mock_stuff, expected)

    def test_second_function(self):
        mock = MockSharedFunctions()
        mock.stuff = some_value
        mock_output = second_function(**args)

        self.assetEqual(mock_output, expected)
        self.assertTrue(True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Here, in the `MockSharedFunctions` you are already inheriting `SharedFunctions`. As `one_important_universal_function` is an abstract method, it needs to be defined.