# why jasmine spy return a function?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, spy

I started messing around with jasmine but I'm having trouble with this code:

```
describe('UserService with errorsServiceSpy and testbed', () => {
    //how to test service that depends by another service
    let userService: UserService;
    let errorsServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<ErrorsHandlerService>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        const spy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ErrorsHandleService', ['getErrors', 'addError']);

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                UserService, { provide: ErrorsHandlerService, useValue: spy }
              ]
        });

        userService = TestBed.inject(UserService);
        errorsServiceSpy = TestBed.inject(ErrorsHandlerService) as jasmine.SpyObj<ErrorsHandlerService>;
    });

    it('should be created', () => {
        expect(userService).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should return user', () => {
        expect(userService.getUser).toBe(userService.user)
    })

    it('#getErrors should return #error value from a spy', () => {
        const error:string = 'prova errore';
        userService.generateError(error)
        let errors:any = errorsServiceSpy.getErrors.toString()
        console.log('errors', errors)
        expect(errorsServiceSpy.getErrors.toString()).toContain(error)
    });

})
```

I state that without testBed or with testBed without spy I can test.
But when I use the spy `errorsServiceSpy.getErrors.toString ()` which should return an array in string, it returns a function: '

```
function() {
    return fn.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

look at all the code in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-service-depends-on-service?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fuser.service.spec.ts)!
pay no attention to the failed test due to 'this.errorsService' I think it's a stackblitz issue

Why it return me a function? How to test the service's method? WHit testBed and spy?
if you need more details I am at your complete disposal

Comment: It's very unclear what your trying to achieve here, do you want to know if `errorsServiceSpy.getErrors` has been invoked in the code your testing?

Comment: That's because your spy has nothing to do with original implementation and all those methods are mocked

Comment: @Liam yes it is invoked nad return a function

Comment: @yurzui that's what I assumed ... so the spy has nothing to do with the service! It's useless?

Comment: No it's not useless @AndreaDiCioccio, [it's a mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665812/what-is-mocking). It allows you to inject dependencies and to test implementation details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking about it wrong, you don't want to get the errors, you want to know if your method has been invoked with a particular parameter, so:

```js
let errors:any = errorsServiceSpy.getErrors.toString()
expect(errorsServiceSpy.getErrors.toString()).toContain(error)
```

Should be:

```js
expect(errorsServiceSpy.getErrors).toHaveBeenCalledWith(error);
```

Though you don't actually show what `getErrors` does so the actual implementation will vary. I'd suggest you [read the docs](https://jasmine.github.io/2.5/introduction#section-Spies)

*Also please be consistent with the semi colons in your code*

Comment: I was following angular's guide on unit tests. the test I would like to do is verify that getErrors actually returns me the errors generated.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, `errorsServiceSpy` is a spy, it only returns what you tell it to return. You don't test spies/mocks, the spies/mocks are hard coded pieces of functionality to allow you to test other things. If you want it to actually do something you have to inject the real implementation of this test, not a spy.

Comment: ho corretto il test suggerito in expect(errorsServiceSpy.addError).toHaveBeenCalledWith(error) e funziona

Comment: lool forgive me! a slip! I understand what you want to tell me ... it's not the test I have to do ...

Comment: in fact if you look at the code in the stackblitz there are other tests with the service itself injected. ok! thank you

Comment: Niente, in bocca al lupo