# Testing Library React vs Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, redux-saga, react-testing-library

I have a really big application with react(lot of pages, modals, tables,etc) and I'm using redux-saga for managing the state. I have a lote of stores and almost in all the components I use the useSelector method for getting the data from the store and many hooks inside them because of logic.

I want to start testing the application, specially to avoid that the app crashes when there is data undefined, invalid, etc. What library do you recommend me to apply in this case ?

Answer (score 120):

**React Testing Library** and **Jest** both have different responsibilities "react testing library" is not a test runner meaning when u enter command `npm test` or `npm run test`
it is **jest responsibility** that collect all the files ending with `.test.js` and runs each test case and show pass and fail results in your console like below

[image]

**react testing library** provides you function to catch dom element and perform some action below are some of its function

```
render, fireEvent, waitFor, screen
```

you can also use **Enzyme**(another popular testing library) for such function to access dom element

EXTRA: developer often confuse among

- jest
- react-testing-library
- Enzyme

Here **Enzyme** and **react-testing-library** are two similar things and alternatives to each other means you can use

- enzyme with jest or
- react-testing-library with jest
- you can also use all three i.e react-testing-library+Enzyme with jest
- but you can not use Enzyme and react-testing-library without jest or any other test runner eg: Mocha

where jest(testing-framework) will collect all .test.js files execute all the test cases and put the output in console with detail like how many pass and fail and react-testing-library or enzyme(both are testing library) will help you to perform event and accessing dom element

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the great answer. You cleared my doubts about the differences between Enzyme, Jest and React-Testing-Library :-)

Comment: Warning: enzyme is officially deprecated and doesn't work with newer react versions.

Answer (score 83):

**Common Questions/Confusions for React Developers**

*Create-React-App & Vite Included*

**What is React Testing Library?**

Provides virtual DOMs for tests - Any time we are running tests without a browser, we need to have a virtual DOM so we can do things like click elements and we can see if virtual DOM behaves like it should do (like changing colour of a div on a button click and so on).

**How Jest is related to React Testing Library?**

- Jest is a Javascript testing library(not only for React, but for any JS related framework or library).Jest is a **test runner** and is responsible for

  - Finding Tests
  - Running the tests
  - Determining whether the tests pass or fail
- **Both React Testing Library and Jest work together** (look at the below image to understand this point

[image: Relationship between React-Testing-Library and Jest]

- **Create-React-App** comes with React-Testing-Library by default which also includes Jest, so you don't need to install anything else
- **Vite** doesn't come with React-Testing-Library built-in. We need to use [Vitest](https://vitest.dev/) testing framework [recommended by RTL](https://testing-library.com/docs/svelte-testing-library/setup/). You can follow this video [to setup React-Testing-Library with vitest](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aqz43LVbnTk&t=674s&ab_channel=LearnfromScratch)

**What is Enzyme and Mocha?**

Enzyme (developed by Airbnb) is an alternative to React-Testing-Library (but not Jest).
Remember from the above screenshot that React-Testing-Library was used to provide virtual DOM. Similar thing in some variations will be done by Enzyme. Enzyme, like RTL is also not a Test Runner, so it might need a runner like Jest.

*Mocha is an alternative to Jest*

Below combinations are possible

- React Testing Library  + Jest `(React's recommended combination, inbuilt into Create-React-App)`
- Enzyme + Jest
- React Testing Library + Mocha
- Enzyme + Mocha

**What are the different type of Tests?**

- **Unit Testing**

  - Tests one unit of code at a time. May be a single function or a component without depending on other units
- **Integration Testing**

  - Tests how multiple units work together. Testing interaction between different functions/units/components
- **Functional / Behavioural Testing**

  - Functional testing means testing the behaviour of a function/software. We might be testing if the software does the right thing with the particular set of data. That might be an integration test as it might have to interact with different units. So the functional test can be an integration test as well
  - The functional test can also be a simple unit test. Let's say on a button click, the div turns red. This might be a simple unit test but still it can also be considered as a functional test as it tests for a particular behaviour of CLICK TURNS RED OR NOT
  - So, the functional test means, not testing the code but testing the behaviour. React-Testing-Library encourages functional tests
- **Acceptance/End-to-End(E2E) test**

  - This is an End-to-End testing where we need a browser and might also need the server
  - Popular tools for E2E testing are **[Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) and [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/)**

    - Cypress supports only Javascript whereas Selenium supports all popular languages like Java, Python, Ruby, C#, Php, etc. [Check - Cypress Vs Selenium](https://www.testim.io/blog/cypress-vs-selenium/)
  - React-Testing-Library doesn't support E2E testing

**What is Mocking or Stubbing?**

Let me explain this with a scenario. Let's say you have made a website for checking the climate of different cities. This app goes and gets the data (using fetch or axios library) from an external source called Weather-API. You can search for any city and it gives you proper climatic conditions.

Now we need to test this app. Let's say we are writing a unit test to test the function that has this functionality where, when a city is passed as a param it makes a call to an external API (Weather-API in this case), fetches the data and then you can write an expect statement to test if the expected value is equal to the fetched value.

If you take a closer look here, we are actually calling Weather-API in our test as well every time we run the unit test. The disadvantages of this approach are:

- We are testing the external API in our app (which is not required)
- If we do this, we are wasting our API calls (which are billed in most cases)
- We don't need to test external API as Weather-API developers might have already tested it and we need to worry about testing only our app and not the external service

So what's the solution here? The solution is to mimic the response from the external API and use it in our test as the actual value and we can test this against the expected value. This is called Mocking. The reason we are doing this is we already know what the external service gives us back and we don't have to call that API anymore but simply hardcode the values as the actual values.

**Reference**: [Testing React with Jest and React Testing - Bonnie Schulkin](https://www.udemy.com/course/react-testing-library/)

**Resources**:

To understand the testing and mocking those tests, these are some good **free youtube videos**

- [JavaScript Testing - Unit, Integration & e2e - Max, Academind](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9HdJ8P6GQI)
- [JavaScript Testing - Mocking Async Code - Max, Academind](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Fl5GH4eYZ8)
- [React Testing Library Crash Course - Laith Academy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04BBgg8zgWo)
- [Stackoverflow - What is mocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665812/what-is-mocking?noredirect=1&lq=1)

To understand in more depth, these are some **paid udemy courses**

- [The React Testing Library Bootcamp - Laith Harb](https://www.udemy.com/course/the-react-testing-library-bootcamp/)
- [Testing React with Jest and React Testing - Bonnie Schulkin](https://www.udemy.com/course/react-testing-library/)

Answer (score 32):

React Testing Library is not an alternative to Jest, because they need each other and every one of them has a clear task.

Jest is a test runner, which gives you the ability to run tests with Jest from the command line. In addition, Jest offers you functions for test suites, test cases, and assertions.
React Testing Library, in contrast to Jest, is one of the testing libraries to test React components.

If you are using create-react-app, Jest (and React Testing Library) comes by default with the installation. If you are using a custom React setup, you need to install and set up Jest (and React Testing Library) yourself.

You might want to look for more on: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react & https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/. Also you can follow up for more on issues and disscusions on github channels of the libraries.

Answer (score 1):

### JEST

> "Jest is a delightful JavaScript Testing Framework with a focus on
> simplicity. It works with projects using: Babel, TypeScript, Node,
> React, Angular, Vue, and more!"

src: [jest](https://jestjs.io/)

***TLDR***: Jest allows you to test any of the above without much boilerplate quickly. As a framework, the framework's code calls your test code. Jest looks for changes made to the code to run specific test cases etc. You can write test's for React just using Jest ([react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html))

### React Testing Library

> "The React Testing Library is a very light-weight solution for testing React components. It provides light utility functions on top of react-dom and react-dom/test-utils, in a way that encourages better testing practices".
> src: [RTL](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/)

***TLDR***: It is a library (i.e., you call the code). It provides some utilities on top of just using Jest and the default react-dom/jest-utils that help us write tests quickly and with less boilerplate (using multiple act() calls etc.) and closer to real-life use (accessibility)

Use RTL with mock server workers to make your life easier for large projects.