# Mock only works for test file, but not when executing instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, content-management-system

I am trying to mock a method used by the class I'm testing. The method is located in the same file as the class I'm testing.

The tested file:

```
export function trackErrors() {
    console.log("This SHOULD NOT BE SEEN ON tests");
    // Currently this console log is visible hwne running tests
}

// Component that is tested 
export const form = () => {
    return <FormComponent callback={trackErrors} />
}
```

The test itself:

**With mock**

The `jest.mock()` is the first thing to happen, before the import.

```
jest.mock('./testedFile', () => {
    const actualModule = jest.requireActual('./testedFile')

    return new Proxy(actualModule, {
        get: (target, property) => {
            switch (property) {
                case 'trackErrors': {
                    return jest.fn()
                }
                default: {
                    return target[property]
                }
            }
        },
    })
})

import * as SModule from "./testedFile";

it.only("Calls trackErrors", async () => {
      const { getByTestId } = <SModule.form />;

      await typeEmail(getByTestId, "abcd");

      await waitFor(() => {
        expect(SModule.trackErrors).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      });
});
```

This **does not work**. When printing `SModule.trackErrors`, I can see the mocked function being put out. But when the test is executed, the test fails with 0 calls and I see this **console.log** **This SHOULD NOT BE SEEN ON tests**. That means that the method is mocked good inside the test, but when rendering the component it continues to call the prexistent method (the one not modked).

I've also tried the **spyOn** approach, but the outcome is exactly the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Mocking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665812/what-is-mocking)

Comment: Not really, this is a specific example with Jest not overrding the mocked function.