# Unit testing code having database dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I am using Junit4 in Spring boot application. I am able to write tests that don't have dependency on database but facing trouble in testing code having DB dependency. Like below test is for a method written in service class that return a Country object when a country matches with the country name provided in method param. When I run this test, `result` always assert as `null` as it find no data in underlying list utilized for searching Countries.

Test Method:

```
@Test
public void test_returns_country_by_name() {
    CountryDao mockCountryDao = Mockito.mock(CountryDao.class);

    // Arrange
    CountryServiceImpl countryService = new CountryServiceImpl(mockCountryDao);
    String name = "Canada";

    // Act
    Country result = countryService.getCountryByName(name);

    // Assert
    assertNotNull(result);
    assertEquals(name, result.getName());
}
```

Service Class code:

```
@Service("countryService")
public class CountryServiceImpl implements CountryService {

    private final CountryDao countryDao;

    public CountryServiceImpl(CountryDao countryDao) {
        this.countryDao = countryDao;
    }

    public Country getCountryByName(String name) {
        return findCountryByCondition(c -> name.equalsIgnoreCase(c.getName()));
    }

    private Country findCountryByCondition(Predicate<Country> condition) {
        return getAllCountries().stream().filter(condition).findFirst().orElse(null);
    }

    public List<Country> getAllCountries() {
        List<Country> countries = countryDao.getAllCountries();    
        return countries;
    }
}
```

Here, unless `getAllCountries` method return a list containing "Canada" Country object till then test will get null only.

I want to understand is there any to fix this issue without using an actual database (In-memory or other). Also is my test approach right, or there is some other way people test this kind of code?

Comment: You have only mocked the object but not the behavior (what should happen when a method is called on the mock object). This link will give you an idea about mocking the behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665812/what-is-mocking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned already, when using mocks, you really should also setup the data and expectations of it. One way of doing so is with the Mockito `when` keyword where you programmatically provide behavior. What do I want this mock to return when a certain method is being called, perhaps with certain arguments (if applicable). Do I want to return data? Or do I perhaps want to throw an exception to simulate and verify my error handling?
It's this essential part that is missing from your test setup.

```java
@Test
public void test_returns_country_by_name() {
    CountryDao mockCountryDao = Mockito.mock(CountryDao.class);

    // Arrange
    CountryServiceImpl countryService = new CountryServiceImpl(mockCountryDao);
    Country belgium = new Country("Belgium");
    Country canada = new Country("Canada");
    org.mockito.when(mockCountryDao.getAllCountries()).thenReturn(List.of(belgium, canada));

    // Act
    Country result = countryService.getCountryByName("Canada");

    // Assert
    assertNotNull(result);
    assertEquals(canada, result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is how I was doing. But want to be certain about approach I am following. Although I was adding only single country object in list of countries.